# What is the gradle dependency of JacksonFactory?

Tags: jackson2

I am need to use JacksonFactory for my program but the dependency not working that I found `implementation group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-jackson2', version: '1.31.3'` it work only in **version 1.20.0** but when I use this version Android Studio ask me to update the version and return an error.

My code is `private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();`

Please help me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JacksonFactory` is deprecated. Use `GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()` from `google-api-client-gson` instead.

Answer (score 0):

instead you can use google-http-client-jackson2

here's nvm url for google-http-client-jackson2
[https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson2]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).